# Python Pandas: Filter in dataframe matching a set of multiple items / conditions from another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, database, dataframe

I have a dataframe `y`:

**Table 1:  Main dataframe `y`**

| Numero | Date | location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 01/11/2009 | 0065;686006;AN |
| 1111 | 01/11/2009 | 0065;686006;P6 |
| 1111 | 05/11/2009 | 0065;686675;1P |
| 1111 | 05/11/2009 | 0065;688575;RE |
| 1111 | 06/11/2009 | 0065;686675;1P |
| 1111 | 05/11/2009 | 0065;686006;AN |
| 5654 | 15/11/2009 | 0065;686675;1P |
| 5654 | 15/11/2009 | 0065;565845;2K |
| 5654 | 26/11/2009 | 0065;154224;5O |
| 4581 | 05/12/2009 | 0065;686006;AN |

**Table 2: Conditions dataframe `cond`**

| Info 1 | Info 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 686006;AN | 686006;P6 |
| 565845;2K | 686675;1P |

So I **want to create a new table with the same numero in same date pass through two points** `"686006;AN and 686006;P6"` or `"565845;2K  and 686675;1P"`.

**Desired output:**

| Numero | Date | location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 01/11/2009 | 0065;686006;AN |
| 1111 | 01/11/2009 | 0065;686006;P6 |
| 5654 | 15/11/2009 | 0065;686675;1P |
| 5654 | 15/11/2009 | 0065;565845;2K |

```
dr = y.groupby('Numero')
my_set = []

for a, b in itertools.combinations(y['Date'], 2):
    if op.eq(a,b) == True:
        for elem, group in dr:
            for j in range(len(cond)):
                if group['location'].str.contains(cond['Info 1'][j]).any() and group['location'].str.contains(cond['Info 2'][j]).any():
                    my_set.append(elem)

                
my_train
data_= y.loc[y['Numero'].isin(my_train)]
print(data_)
```

But it doesn't work because large data so out memories and it doesn't print the date and only the value containing the info but all the values of that element.

THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!

Comment: Try to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and explain "doesn't work" in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approach by the following steps:

**Step 1: Create a helper column to extract from `location` the substring in same format as `Info` in `cond`**

```
y['loc_info'] = y['location'].str.split(';', n=1).str[-1]
```

**Step 2: Create a list of 2 points from `cond`**

```
cond_list = cond.apply(set, axis=1).to_list()
```

**Step 3: boolean mask for same `Numero` in same `Date` pass through 2 points**

```
mask = y.groupby(['Numero', 'Date'])['loc_info'].agg(set).apply(lambda x: any([y.issubset(x) for y in cond_list]))
```

**Step 4: locate entries fulfilling boolean mask condition**

```
df_out = y.set_index(['Numero', 'Date']).loc[mask].reset_index()
```

**Step 5 (optional): filter with entries only in `cond`**

In case you want to keep only entries maintained in `cond` (condition not explicitly mentioned in question and not in sample data), you can do a further filtering step:

```
df_out = df_out.loc[df_out['loc_info'].isin(cond.values.ravel())]
```

**Full set of codes:**

```
# Create a helper column to extract from `location` the substring in same format as `Info` in `cond`
y['loc_info'] = y['location'].str.split(';', n=1).str[-1]

# create a list of 2 points from `cond`
cond_list = cond.apply(set, axis=1).to_list()

# boolean mask for same 'Numero' in same 'Date' pass through 2 points
mask = y.groupby(['Numero', 'Date'])['loc_info'].agg(set).apply(lambda x: any([y.issubset(x) for y in cond_list]))

# locate entries fulfilling boolean mask condition
df_out = y.set_index(['Numero', 'Date']).loc[mask].reset_index()

# Optional step to filter with entries only in `cond`
df_out = df_out.loc[df_out['loc_info'].isin(cond.values.ravel())]
```

**Result**

```
print(df_out)

   Numero        Date        location   loc_info
0    1111  01/11/2009  0065;686006;AN  686006;AN
1    1111  01/11/2009  0065;686006;P6  686006;P6
2    5654  15/11/2009  0065;686675;1P  686675;1P
3    5654  15/11/2009  0065;565845;2K  565845;2K
```

You can drop the helper column `loc_info`, as follows:

```
df_out = df_out.drop('loc_info', axis=1)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

   Numero        Date        location
0    1111  01/11/2009  0065;686006;AN
1    1111  01/11/2009  0065;686006;P6
2    5654  15/11/2009  0065;686675;1P
3    5654  15/11/2009  0065;565845;2K
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben.T   :-)

Comment: Thanks your answer and explication. It’s very clear. Thank you so much 

Comment: @Poohlikepooh Welcome!  Pleased to help!   Happy programming :-)

Comment: Hi, It still declares other values like '686006,PN' :(((((

Comment: @Poohlikepooh  Is this value together with other successfully paired values in the same `Numero` and same `Date` ?

Comment: yes, It announces all values

Comment: @Poohlikepooh  I see.  It's the current design that will list all entries under the same `Numero` and same `Date` whenever they include entries passing the 2 points.  If you want to exclude others, we can further do a filtering to filter only those in `cond`.  I'm devising codes for this.

Comment: I am a newbie so there are many problems i am confused, thank you very much for your enthusiasm and your support.

Comment: @Poohlikepooh  No problem.  As you didn't mention you want to only show those entries in `cond` and didn't included such test case in sample data, I interpreted it as you want to show all entries of the same `Numero` and same `Date` whenever they got 2 points passing the required condition.  It's fine you clarify it now.  Editing and will let you have it very soon.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't describe it well :(((

Comment: @Poohlikepooh     See my edit above to add the optional step 5.  No problem, understand that it's not that easy to describe requirements in every detail.  We sometimes can do this by crafting better sample data to showcase this part of requirement.

Comment: It work and I’m very grateful for your help 

Comment: @Poohlikepooh  Welcome!   Note that this additional optional step works to remove entries not in `cond`.  However, if there is further complication that if there is a single entry still in `cond` but not goes in pair as shown in `cond` in the same row, this still cannot do it.  That boundary/edge case requires much more complicated processing to support it.  If you don't need it, I just leave it.

Comment: So in this case, how can i do?

Comment: @Poohlikepooh  As i said, this is far more complicated.  As your entries per `Numero` and `Date` grouping can be freely ordered, we can't know whether entry 1 is to pair with entry 2 or 3, or 4, etc.  The processing time will be much more and run much slower.  We need to inspect every pair of entries in one `cond`  row.   I think that's why your question was left unanswered so long before I see it.  It's a real complicated processing.

Comment: Thanks your progress. Have a good day . If i have a question in the future, how can i connect you???

Comment: @Poohlikepooh  But that edge case will still be rare, hopefully.  It's because we will only extract those `Numero` and `Date` grouping that has at least one pair of values passing through the 2 points of the same row of `cond`.  Otherwise, we won't extract this group of rows from `y`.  And only when there is extra point that's visited only once (without 2 points) will be of problem.  Hopefully should be rare.

Comment: @Poohlikepooh  Welcome!  I'm glad to answer your further question if I see you post a new question in the future and just by luck I see it and no others already answered it well.   No worry, there's lot of experienced contributors and some experts here readily to answer your new question.    Have a nice day!   Happy programming too!

Comment: Have a good day :)))))

Comment: Hello, I have another question. If you have time, you can help me see it??? Thanks you <3 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/69538939/17037971